# How to find the derivative of (x)(sinx)(cosx)? (Mostly simplifying it)

Tags: calculus

Right so using the product rule for 3 expression, I wound up with

$\left(\cos x\right)\left(\sin x\right) - x\sin ^2 x + x\cos ^2 x$.

My main issue is cleaning this up to get the derivative to equal

$\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x + x\cos 2x$.

I am not quite sure where the change from x to 2x came from. I know it's probably some old trig rules that I have forgotten. So if anyone could help with the simplification that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: $\sin 2x=2\sin x \cos x$ and $\cos 2x = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$

Answer (score 3):

Arguably easiest way would be to use the $\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x$ identity *before* taking derivatives:

$$
(x\,\sin x\,\cos x)' = \frac{1}{2}(x\,\sin 2x)' = \frac{1}{2}\big((x)'\,\sin 2x + x\,(\sin 2x)'\big)= \frac{1}{2}\,\sin 2x + x\,\cos 2x
$$

Comment: +1 for being the only one (so far) to emphasize using the identity before differentiating.

Answer (score 0):

Use $\sin x \cos x = (1 / 2) \sin (2 x)$, then substitute $u = 2 x$.  The rest should follow.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the identity:

$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$

and for the other just factor and use an identity:

$-x\sin^2(x)+x\cos^2(x)=x(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x))=x\cos(2x)$

Where the identity is: $\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=\cos(2x)$ since:

$\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$

put $b=a$ and obtain:

$\cos(a+a)=\cos(2a)=\cos(a)\cos(a)-\sin(a)\sin(a)=\cos^2(a)-\sin^2(a)$

Answer (score 0):

$(cosx)(sinx)-xsin^2x+xcos^2x$

as we know :

$(cosx)(sinx) = 0.5sin2x$

$-xsin^2x+xcos^2x = x(cos^2x-sin^2x)=x(cos2x)$

hence the answer is :
$0.5sin2x +x(cos2x)$